# TeamCity and NPM login via OAuth token

Tags: npm, oauth, teamcity

I'm trying to integrate TeamCity Server (Windows) with my private NPM repo. I have create an OAuth token.
But I can't find any examples how to use the token in regards to NPM login alone or via TeamCity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

1. In a PowerShell (run as ADMIN) run this:

   npm login --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
   --scope=@your_npm_handle

(NB. Replace the your_npm_handle in the command above with YOUR private NPM handle!)

2. Enter your username, password and NPM e-mail when prompted

You should now see a successful login to NPM

3. Now run:

   npm config set always-auth true
4. If you now run:

   npm config edit

you should see something like this / 3 lines of code in the file .npmrc

```
@your_npm_handle=https://registry.npmjs.org/
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
always-auth=true
```

5. Please remember: To use a placeholder to your AUTH token ID and place the actual AUTH token in an .env file and only ref. to it in the .npmrc file). Replace this: authToken=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx with this: authToken=${NPM_TOKEN} and in your .env file add this: NPM_TOKEN=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
6. Add this .npmrc file in the ROOT of your project.
7. Commit and publish the .npmrc file to source control (not the .env file!)
8. TeamCity will now download the .npmrc file together with the rest of your source code and run with success because it will use the NPM config file and thereby be able to access your private NPM repo and download all you private @packages.
9. Remember to activate F2A to your NPM account + to your NPM AUTH tokens.

Be aware this solution ONLY works on multiple machines as long as none of the machines don't invalidate this single AUTH token. In this case use a separate AUTH token setup for each machine or simply use NPM LOGIN instead each time.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this while dealing with something similar and i thought sharing a bit, cause the accepted answer is pretty insecure:

a) You should not push your token/keys into a version control. Period. This is a security flaw.

b) You don't need to log in via `npm login` to retrieve your key. You should log in to npmjs.com where you will see a section called "Access Tokens". There you can create tokens to use for this situation and mark them as **read-only** as well. (or you can use command line to create tokens as well)

c) Teamcity offers "parameters". You can set up a secret there to use during the build. You can do this at root or project level. Create an "environment" parameter and mark it as read-only and as a password so it is secure.

d) For example if you have a docker build, pass it in as a `--build-arg NPM_TOKEN=%env.yourTokenName%` as additional parameter, then `${NPM_TOKEN}` can be used in your .npmrc file if you set it up in your Dockerfile correctly (`ARG NPM_TOKEN`)

Comment: As mentioned in my comment to my answer: “npm login” creates the Auth token for you…

Comment: @PabloDK npm login creates a token of the type `publish` for you if there is none, that's correct. you can check this in your npmjs.com settings. But it's not suitable for sharing in a build environment, because the token gives you access to everything your user can do with (publish under your organization for example if you have these roles). So it's safer to create a token for read-only purposes especially if there are used in "to be shared"-environments like teamcity.

Comment: 1. NPM publish via CLI or the creation of an AUTH token via the UI is same same :) 2. Of course never add sensitive credentials to any where they don't belong --> place the credentials in your .env file. 4. Enable F2A to your NPM account / AUTH tokens and you are safe to go :)